# on click event leads to chain of events after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add and remove class followed by click events to perform ajax calls. later on success retrieve back the old class. Like Im changing a state of input field to enable, change text of edit button to save and adding class at the same time. when i click same button it has to send modified value in input field to api and restore back to original save button. This is happening for first time when I click edit button. After saving if I click the edit button its changing the state to save and edit back again.help needed.

```
           $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            if (parseInt(cat_id[i].innerHTML) == value.category.id) {
                base_rate[i].value = value.base_rate;
                ast[i].innerHTML = value.service_type.name;
                airportEditId[i].setAttribute("id",value.id);
                newEvent = value.id;
                airportEditId[i].classList.add("fireevent"+value.id);
                j = true;
                base_rate[i].setAttribute("disabled",true);
                      $('.fireevent'+value.id).on('click',function(){
                        $(this).attr("id",value.id);
                        $(this).parents("tr").find("input").prop('disabled',false);
                        $(this).text("save");
                        $(this).removeClass().addClass("smokeevent"+value.id).addClass("btn btn-primary");
                        console.log(this);


                      $('.smokeevent'+value.id).on('click',function(){
                           var airport = {
                              "updated_by":{{user.id}},
                              "city":parseInt($('#city_list option:selected').val()),
                              "service_type":parseInt($('#select_service1 option:selected').val()),
                              "base_rate":parseInt($(this).parents("tr").find("input").val()),
                              "vehicle_varient":[1,2]
                           };

                           console.log(airport);
                         $.ajax({
                            url: '/rapido/api/update_airportratecard/'+value.id+'/',
                            method: 'PUT',
                            headers:{'X-CSRFToken':'{{ csrf_token }}'},                  
                            contentType : 'application/json',
                            context:this,
                            data: JSON.stringify(airport),
                            success:function(res){
                              console.log(this);
                              $(this).text("Edit");
                              $(this).parents("tr").find("input").prop('disabled',true);
                              $(this).removeClass().addClass("btn btn-success");
                            }
                         });
                      });
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In a loop, there are multiple events attached for the same click.
let go off the earlier event and attach again.
    $('.airportdata').off('click').on('click', ...

Comment: It did not work for me. only first time the flow went correctly. second time it did not trigger the event itself

Answer (score 0):

You are ***binding the event to elements through class selector*** in a loop.

By the end of the loop you will have multiple event handlers assigned to all the elements belong to that class. As a result of this, **one trigger of a click will invoke all those event handlers**.

Instead use your own `airportEditId[i]` to bind the event instead of

```
$( airportEditId[i] ).on('click',function(){
```

**Note :Judging by this line**

```
$(".airportdata").removeClass().addClass("airport_editid").addClass("btn btn-success");
```

`airport_editid` and `airportdata` are classes of same element. Hence you can replace both by `$( airportEditId[i] ).on('click',function(){`

**Edit**

Another approach could be to pull these two click event handlers outside the loop and bind them separately

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  if (parseInt(cat_id[i].innerHTML) == value.category.id) {
    base_rate[i].value = value.base_rate;
    ast[i].innerHTML = value.service_type.name;
    airportEditId[i].setAttribute("id", value.id);
    newEvent = value.id;
    j = true;
    base_rate[i].setAttribute("disabled", true);
  }
});
$(".airport_editid").on('click', function() { //notice that this line is outside
  $(this).parents("tr").find("input").prop('disabled', false);
  $(this).text("save");
  $(this).removeClass().addClass("airportdata").addClass("btn btn-primary");

  $(this).on('click', function() { //notice that this line is using `this` instead of selector
    var airport = {
      "updated_by": {
        {
          user.id
        }
      },
      "city": parseInt($('#city_list option:selected').val()),
      "service_type": parseInt($('#select_service1 option:selected').val()),
      "base_rate": parseInt($(this).parents("tr").find("input").val()),
      "vehicle_varient": [1, 2]
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: api,
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
      },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(airport),
      success: function(res) {        $(".airportdata").parents("tr").find("input").prop('disabled', true);
        $(".airportdata").text("Edit");        $(".airportdata").removeClass().addClass("airport_editid").addClass("btn btn-success");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: the variable airportEditId is reading class airport_editid. Will this work?

Comment: @SriharshaK Sorry, didn't understood your question. `airportEditId[i]` seems to be an element based on this line from your code `airportEditId[i].setAttribute("id",value.id);`. And based on the other line I have highlighted in my answer, this element may have both classes `airport_editid` and `airportdata`.

Comment: exactly i tried using this $(airportEditId[i]) but its the same didnt not work

Comment: @SriharshaK Can you create a working snippet using `<>` to replicate your issue in your question itself?

Comment: i dont want two events inside loop to bind

Comment: this doesn't work...the event is binding each time I click edit...it send performing to set of operations at a time since its in loop

Comment: @SriharshaK oh...ok, In that case I don't think I can help without looking at a replicated issue.